# SPF + WHM Hostname

Tags: email, cpanel, spam-prevention, whm, spf

G'day,

I've added SPF entries for my cPanel accounts, no worries there.

However, when I do a email spam check I noticed that the WHM server hostname gets a  penalty for not having an SPF entry. Here is the output of a spam check for an email (I've changed the server / IP for public discussion):

> You do not have a SPF record, please add the following one to your domain server1.example.com:
>
> v=spf1 a mx ip4:123.12.12.123 ~all

Just rehashing, SPF is configured for example.com and works fine. However, SPF is not configured for the WHM server hostname server1.example.com. WHM doesn't appear to allow anything but "A" entries for the hostname; any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

> Home »DNS Functions »Edit DNS Zone

select the dns zone for server.example.com. Try adding a new record at the bottom in the section "Add New Entries Below this Line" as

server.example.com. and select the record as TXT enter the SPF record

> v=spf1 a mx ip4:123.12.12.123 ~all

SAVE

Comment: cheers Leo, I have entered this and will give it a day to propagate before testing it again

Comment: Cheers to you to. Check after some hours. try from command line dig domain.com TXT. If that shows your record, Lets have some beer :)